# Django что возвращает в случае неудачной аутентификации?

Tags: python-3.x, django

Есть форма авторизации (не из коробки django).
В случае неудачной аутентификации нужно выплюнуть блок с уведомлением об ошибке.
По задумке сделать внутри html страницы что-то вроде:

`{ if form.errors}

{endif}`

Вопрос в том, что возвращает django в случае неудачи? Что именно ловить и вставлять вместо 'form.errors'?

Comment: Возвращает где? Если "не из коробки", лучше покажите эту самую форму

Comment: Просто форма авторизации из Bootstrap4.
Вопрос в том, что django возвращает в случае введенных логина и пароля, которых нет в базе данных пользователей? 
Мне подсказали, что все ошибки с формами он выплевывает в "form.errors", но конструкция описаная выше не работает. Блок (div с красным текстом предупреждения о неверно введенном логине или пароле) помещенный внутри кода django вываливается сразу на странице авторизации.